# Elegant way to do multiple parameter filter for client-side search

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6

So, say I have an object that looks like the following:

```
const DEVICES: { mac: string; name: string; ip: string; type: number }[] = [
  {
    mac: 'xx:xx:xx:xx:xx',
    name: 'something',
    ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx.xx',
    type: 0,
  },
  {
    mac: 'xx:xx:xx:xx:yy',
    name: 'something1',
    ip: 'xx.xx.xx.xx.yy',
    type: 1,
  },
  // and so on...
];
```

When I wanted to have multiple searchable parameters (name, mac, ip) - what's intuitive to me is to put some `||` (ORs) inside my filter function like:

```
 DEVICES.filter((item) => {
   return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(dataFromInputEvent.trim().toLowerCase()) >= 0
          || item.ip.toLowerCase().indexOf(dataFromInputEvent.trim().toLowerCase()) >= 0
          || item.mac.toLowerCase().indexOf(dataFromInputEvent.trim().toLowerCase()) >= 0;
 })
 .map(item, index) = {
   return (
     <SomeComponent
       key={index}
       type={item.type}
       name={item.name}
       mac={item.mac}
       type={item.type}
     />
   );
 )}
```

as you can see, if the data gets more properties and if I were to add another parameter for search, I would just put another `||` inside the filter function to return. Is there a more elegant way to to do multiple parameter search - ideally without repeating the same `toLowerCase()` and `indexOf()`? or maybe not doing the `||` thing altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an array of the properties to filter (currently, `['name', 'ip', 'mac']`), then iterate over them and see if `.some` of them, when accessed with bracket notation on `item`, include the data:

```
DEVICES.filter((item) => {
  const input = dataFromInputEvent.trim().toLowerCase();
  return ['name', 'ip', 'mac'].some(prop => item[prop].toLowerCase().includes(input));
})
.map( // ...
```

(note that you can make the code much less repetitive by storing the trimmed and lower-cased input in a variable first, and by using `.includes` instead of `indexOf`)

You also probably meant to type `DEVICES` as an array of objects, not a single object:

```
const DEVICES: Array<{ mac: string; name: string; ip: string; type: number }> = [
```

But Typescript can almost infer types without you having to explicitly note them, so

```
const DEVICES = [
```

alone would probably be enough. (less code to write means less surface area for errors, and often also makes things more readable)

Comment: so say I've typed the DEVICES with an array and made an array of searchable properties how would type the arguments of `.filter` and `.some` function? :)

Comment: Ah, the `item[prop]` doesn't compile. Since you're sure it'll always be a string, you can use `(item[prop] as string)`. Another option is to declare the `prop` array as `const`, so that its values are interpreted as static, rather than being generalized: `(['name', 'ip', 'mac'] as const).some`. I think that's all you need to do - just pick one of those.

Comment: `(item[prop] as string)` does not work for some reason. I'm not sure if it's good to do hardcoded array of strings like that. I feel it's going to be leary to maintain. Maybe I'd declare it somewhere like `const searchableProperties = ['name', 'ip'];` then call the variable maybe?

Comment: Oops, I had a different type def than you when playing around. Yeah, that method won't work, so you'll have to use the other one, with `as const`

Comment: I'm not familiar with `as` does that create a new variable every iteration? how is different from declaring `const searchableProperties = ['name', 'ip'];` ?

Comment: The `as const` notation is simply an indication to the type-checker that it should interpret the previous expression *exactly as it is*, without trying to generalize. Without it, the array of property names gets typed as `string[]` - with it, the array of property names gets typed as `['name', 'ip', 'mac']`, allowing `item[prop]` later to be correctly deduced to be of type `string`.

Comment: I see, my editor shows that the type of the `prop` now is `'name' | 'ip' | 'mac'`